# Exclude package from build but not from view in Netbeans 8?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I exclude a specific package (e.g. com.domain.various) from the build process, so that it doesn't show up in the final jar file?

I already tried to it the following way:

1. Right-Click Project -> Project Properties
2. Select "Sources" in the tree
3. Click Includes/Excludes -> add exclude pattern

But this also hides the package within the Netbeans IDE, but I still need the package in the project-view...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can customize targets for NetBeans build. It uses Ant as the default build tool.
There is no way of doing it using NetBeans menus. You must edit `build.xml` and override the compilation/jar creation targets of `build-impl.xml`.

**EDIT**:

There is a property on `nbproject/project.properties`:

```
# Files in build.classes.dir which should be excluded from distribution jar
dist.archive.excludes=
```

Just edit it with the files you want to exclude (there are examples on `project.properties`. For example, to exclude all files from `my.package.to.exclude`:

```
dist.archive.excludes=**/my/package/to/exclude/**
```